# Android application cannot find shared object

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, gstreamer, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have cross-compiled a gstreamer plugin for android. The .so file is installed in the same place as the other gstreamer plugins. I then build an android app having added the cross-compiled plugin name to my Android.mk file (the plugin name is passed to a seperate gstreamer-1.0.mk file to create the libgstandroid.so which is installed alongside the app on the phone).

I'm not yet using the plugin in my application source code, I am just attempting to build/include it in my app as a first step. When the app loads it has a FATAL EXCEPTION:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libgstplugin.so" not found
```

I'm not sure how to debug; it seems the plugin isn't being linked correctly into the libgstandroid.so?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by building a static plugin library (and deleting the existing shared library as the gstreamer make process seems to choose the .so by default)